# Elastic Cloud APM showing "failed to find message" in Transactions log Page

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm, elastic-apm, open-telemetry-collector

How to makes Kibana to show logs in APM "Transactions" page under "Logs" tab. I verified the logs are successfully being generated with the "trace.id",but its display  failed to find message in log

[[image: [enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFTIP.png)]]

[image]
Need to display with full description of message